# Python: changing the value of array elements based on multiple subsets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to modify the values of an array based on a subset of a subset, but I can't find a way to do this. I think this exposes my lack of understanding about exactly how array indexing and subsetting works and what views are, but I can't find a solution anywhere so I am hoping that someone can help me.

**Example problem:**

```
import numpy as np

#generate some simple data
MyArray=np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)

>>>MyArray
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

#subset 1
i=np.where(MyArray > 5)

#subset of that subset
j=np.where(MyArray[i] < 15)

>>>MyArray[i][j]
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

Great, that's what I expected to see! But if I now want to change those values to something else, I can't:

```
>>>MyArray[i][j]=999
>>>MyArray[i][j]
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])

#hmmmm :(
```

**An ugly solution that works**

I CAN get the values to change by looping over the elements of `j`  individually, but this seems extraordinarily clumsy & hard to read:

```
#get number of elements in j
nj=np.size(j)

#loop over each element of j and modify the corresponding ith element 
of MyArray 
for j_it in range(0,nj):
    MyArray[i[0][j[0][j_it]]][i[1][j[0][j_it]]]=999

>>>MyArray
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
       [  5, 999, 999, 999, 999],
       [999, 999, 999, 999, 999],
       [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19]])
```

Similarly, I **can** modify `MyArray` using just one level of subsetting:

```
ii=np.where((MyArray > 5) & (MyArray < 15))
MyArray[ii]=999
>>>MyArray
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
       [  5, 999, 999, 999, 999],
       [999, 999, 999, 999, 999],
       [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19]])
```

So, where am I going wrong with the first example?

NOTE:- I know that my last solution works fine for this problem, but my actual problem necessarily involves far more data and the second level of subsetting (and possibly a third...)

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this is something simple that I really should be able to work out fo myself from the documentation: I just haven't been able to :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, your last example solves your problem.  The issue you're missing is that calling `MyArray[i]` creates a new array which you are then indexing again with `MyArray[i][j]`.  When you attempt to assign to the result of this subset, you aren't actually assigning into `MyArray`.

To do this similar to your first example, you would want to do everything in one operation like this:

```
import numpy as np

#generate some simple data
MyArray=np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)

>>>MyArray
MyArray([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

#subset 1
i=np.where(MyArray > 5)

#subset of that subset
j=np.where(MyArray[i] < 15)

# Mask array subset
MyArray[i[0][j[0]], i[1][j[0]]] = 999

>>>MyArray
MyArray([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
   [  5, 999, 999, 999, 999],
   [999, 999, 999, 999, 999],
   [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19]])
```

Basically, `i` and `j` are both tuples containing arrays indicating which indexes were matched in the `where` statement.  `i` contains two arrays, one for each dimensions in `MyArray`.  `j` contains one array for the single dimension of the arrays contained in `i`.  You want to get the `j[0]` elements of both of the arrays in `i`.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: That makes lots of sense and thanks very much for the explanation. Just to note, for anybody else who comes across this, this solution also works if subset `j` is calculated from a different array (`MyArray2`) so long as its dimensions are the same as `MyArray` (so that `MyArray2[i]` provides the same subset as `MyArray[i]`). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating boolean arrays:

```
condition_1 = MyArray > 5
condition_2 = MyArray < 15
```

Then you can use bitwise **&**:

```
bools = condition1 & condition2
```

which will have values like:

```
[[ False,  False,  False,  False,  False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  ...]...]
```

If such array has the same lengths as the array you want to change data in, you can use it as you use indexes. But here instead of indexes you have True or False based on if a cell meet your conditions.

```
MyArray[bools] = 999
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answer from @Vorticity is clearly correct and a well thought out explanation, I feel that a different piece of code is significantly more readable and understandable.

From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html
we can tell np what values to use after our boolean in the first arg to np.where gets evaluated.

```
>>>np.where((MyArray > 5) & (MyArray < 15), MyArray, 999)

array([[999, 999, 999, 999, 999],
   [999,   6,   7,   8,   9],
   [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14],
   [999, 999, 999, 999, 999]])
```

That being said, a good example of the "not assigning to `MyArray` issue would be the following:

```
>>> MyArray
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
>>> MyArray = MyArray[i]
>>> MyArray
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
>>> MyArray = MyArray[j]
>>> MyArray
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

I think the main thing that trips a lot of people (myself included) is that just calling `MyArray[i]` without assigning it to something with `=` doesn't make the computer hold onto what the result of that less than or greater than comparison was.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an alternative solution and some helpful clarification on the problem. Regarding your solution, I am a little unsure what you mean by `test` on the first line? Something that I have found that works, following your solution, is: `MyArray[i]=np.where(MyArray[i] < 15, 999, MyArray[i])`, which sets those elements of `MyArray[i]` that are less than 15 to 999, and leaves the rest unchanged.

Comment: oh lol sorry when I was recreating your situation in IDLE i made my array as "test" not "MyArray." It is just a typo. I will edit appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

[maskedarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) looks like it has the right set of tools

```
import numpy.ma as ma


MyArray=np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)

subma = ma.masked_inside(MyArray, 5, 15)  # lots of ma. logic, arithematic ops

subma.filled(999)

Out[44]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
       [999, 999, 999, 999, 999],
       [999, 999, 999, 999, 999],
       [999,  16,  17,  18,  19]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see that this solution works for my example, but what about if I had another array, `MyArray2`, that I am creating the second subset (`j`) from? i.e:

`MyArray=np.arange(2).reshape(4,5) \ `
`MyArray2=np.arange(20)*10.reshape(4,5) \ `
`i=np.where(MyArray > 5) \ `
`j=np.where(MyArray2[i] < 100) ` 

Perhaps I should have been clearer in my question, but I want to be able to modify `MyArray` based on subset `j`, which I don't _think_ (although I could be wrong) the maskedarray approach lets me do?